# Online Depictions of the Colorful Second Temple

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, talmud-bavli, architecture-design, archaeology

Are there any artistic depictions, available online, of the multicolored appearance of the Second Temple, based on archaeological finds (see, e.g., [here](http://patternsofevidence.com/blog/2016/09/15/magnificent-flooring-from-jerusalems-second-temple-unearthed/)), or, e.g., the depiction of the blue/green and white wavelike appearance of the Temple walls, as presented in [Bava Batra 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.4a.6?lang=bi) and [Sukka 51b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.51b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?

(See also [Josephus, Of The War, Book V](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-5.html).)

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/multi/mikdash/mikdash-2.htm

Comment: The mini Jerusalem model at the Israel Museum is apparently based on archaeological sources. Also note the apparent artistic depictions of the Temple on coins of Bar-Kokhba and elsewhere.

Comment: @Argon Thanks. Do you happen to know if they depict the multicolored marble and if there are any pictures online?

Comment: @Argon I think that is the popular Holyland model, which seems to ignore these sources and is almost entirely white.

Comment: @Argon It's definitely an impressive model, but it does seem Professor Avi-Yonah who designed it ignored or discounted the above linked sources for some reason.

Comment: @Argon (Perhaps based on his read of Josephus?)